# How to pass lambda to function that requires class parameter

Tags: c++, lambda

Edit: `Compare` was a given parameter class type, so I have created `struct Compare`, but i don't know how to cast the `lambda` variable passed in test to `Compare` class, which is a wanted parameter type.

Edit2: Alright guys, I think I sounded pretty unclear, so I'm posting the whole assignment text.

> Create clamp function with two overloads
>
> ```
> T const & clamp (T const & value, T const & low, T const & high)
> T const & clamp (T const & value, T const & low, T const & high, Compare cmp)
> ```
>
> which returns `low` if `value` is less than `low`, `high` if `value` is greater than `high`, and otherwise value. In other words, value is limited to the range `[low, high]`.
> The first overload assumes that T is comparable using the `<operator`, the second `>overload` then takes a suitable comparator as the 4th argument.

Unit test for the second overload is this:

```
TEST_CASE("Clamping using a custom lambda", "[all]") {
    const int low = 255;
    const int high = 0;
    auto cmp = [](int lhs, int rhs) { return std::abs(lhs) > std::abs(rhs); };
    int value, expected;
    std::tie(value, expected) = GENERATE(values<std::pair<int, int>>({
            {-1, -1},
            {256, 255},
            {-256, 255},
            {244, 244},
            {0, 0},
            {-22, -22},
            {-255, -255},
            {255, 255}
    }));
    REQUIRE(clamp(value, low, high, cmp) == expected);
}
```

Now, I am just making and submitting `header` file. And I don't know how to cast the 4th parameter, which is a lambda function, to a `Compare` that from assignment looks like a `struct` that I have to implement.

Remember, I cannot change the function declaration.

Comment: We have no idea what `Compare` is. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Your prototype is not a valid templated function prototype. Please post the complete code.

Comment: *so I have created struct Compare* What? It's supposed to be a template parameter. You don't define a struct... I'm confused. Show some code please.

Comment: You don't have to create an operator in some `Compare` class and link it to a lambda... (that's what it sounds like your are trying to do). If you declare a lambda function, this is a variable of a particular type. That type **is** your "class". The operator will depend on the input/output types of your lambda, and will perform whatever you designed your lambda to do.

Comment: Sorry guys, I am dumbass, like we did not cover the templates and i thought It had to be class type. Anyways, thank you all for helping me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing in the posted assignment that says `Compare` is expected to be a struct/class type that you have to implement.

There are only 3 ways to pass a lambda in a function parameter:

- if the parameter is a plain function pointer, and the lambda is non-capturing.
- if the parameter is defined as a template type.
- if the parameter is defined as a `std::function`.

So, unless `Compare` in your case is defined as an alias for either `int(*)(int,int)` or `std::function<int(int,int)>`, then `Compare` should be a template parameter instead.  That will allow the caller to decide what type it wants to use for the `cmp` callback.  `Compare` should not be an actual class type of its own.

For example:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename Compare>
T const& clamp(T const& value, T const& low, T const& high, Compare cmp)
```

This would allow the caller to pass in *anything* that `clamp()` can call using `cmp(param1, param2)` - which can include:

- a plain function:

```cpp
int compareInts(int lhs, int rhs) { return std::abs(lhs) > std::abs(rhs); }

REQUIRE(clamp(value, low, high, compareInts) == expected);
```

- a `std::bind()`'ed class method:

```cpp
class CompareInts {
public:
    int compare(int lhs, int rhs) { return std::abs(lhs) > std::abs(rhs); }
};

using namespace std::placeholders; 

CompareInts obj;
auto cmp = std::bind(&CompareInts::compare, &obj, _1, _2);

REQUIRE(clamp(value, low, high, cmp) == expected);
```

- a functor implementing `operator()`:

```cpp
struct CompareInts {
    int operator()(int lhs, int rhs) { return std::abs(lhs) > std::abs(rhs); }
};

REQUIRE(clamp(value, low, high, CompareInts{}) == expected);
```

- a lambda:

```cpp
auto cmp = [](int lhs, int rhs) { return std::abs(lhs) > std::abs(rhs); };

REQUIRE(clamp(value, low, high, cmp) == expected);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Compare` can a generic type. Then it won't matter what's passed in - as long as it's invokable, it'll work:

```
#include <functional>

template <tyepname T, class Compare>
T const & clamp (T const & value, T const & low, T const & high, Compare greater) {
  if (std::invoke(greater, value, high))) return high;
  if (std::invoke(greater, value, low))) return value;
  return low;
}
```

Also note that in C++ the argument names are not relevant in declarations and are ignored there, i.e. the declaration can use cryptic argument names, or even none at all. Now note that `cmp` here is not something that anyone should be teaching: it's impossible to tell at a glance what it's supposed to do. There's no need to write a comment about it. The name of the argument should be, obviously, `greater`. Hereby I apologize for all the times I wrote `cmp` instead of `less` or `greater` or `equals` - I'm sure some of this inertia has tainted my answers on SO. Mea culpa, and it was a stupid thing to do, I admit :)

So it's perfectly fine to have the *declaration* unchanged as per requirements, but still use argument names that don't make your blood boil in the *definition*:

```
// declaration
template <typename T, class Compare>
T const & clamp (T const & value, T const & low, T const & high, Compare cmp);

// definition
template <typename T, class Compare>
T const &clamp(T const &value, T const &low, T const &high, Compare greater);
```

I also find it rather confusing that the declarations offered in the assignment refer to some `T`, but it's not specified whether `T` is a constant type, or a generic type (i.e. a type parameter to a template).

You have to read the assignment carefully and divine whether `T` is something that is a constant type provided to you, but not specified in the assignment itself (i.e. a requirement imposed on you), or whether `T` means that your code must accept any type that will work in these circumstances. If that's not clear - ask the professor, because this sort of stuff is so fundamental that I'm baffled it wouldn't be clearly stated. My expectation is that you'd have included this ever-important detail were it provided in the assignment!

It is possible to "solve" the assignment in three circumstances that may arise - you need to determine what is expected of you, and if it takes you longer than 15 minutes to figure it all, absolutely, positively ask the instructor.

### T and Compare are fixed types defined in test environment, but not provided a-priori

In other words, the test environment defines an arbitrary `T` and `Compare`, i.e. that they are fixed types with those names in global scope, then your functions won't be function templates - and in this case you do not care what `T` nor `Compare` is - they must be "well behaved" enough types to be usable, i.e. that a reasonable solution to the assignment exists. To write such code, make sensible assumptions to get it to compile, and then *remove* the definitions - since they'd clash with what the test environment provides.

```
// remove before running tests - this would be provided by test code
using T = int;
using Compare = bool(*)(T, T);
// end remove before running tests

T const & clamp (T const & value, T const & low, T const & high, Compare greater) {
  // your implementation here
}
```

### T and Compare are meant to be fixed types determined from looking at test cases

For example, the test case you have shown implies that:

`T = int`, and `Compare = bool(*)(int, int)`.

In that case, I'd still use the aliases `T` and `Compare`, but just set them to those determined types:

```
// do not remove those
using T = int;
using Compare = bool(*)(int, int);

T const & clamp (T const & value, T const & low, T const & high, Compare greater)  {
  // your code here
}
```

### T and Compare do not name actual types, and are not constant

Then you need to make your functions generic - i.e. so that they also take the types as (template) arguments:

```
template <typename T, typename Compare>
T const & clamp (T const & value, T const & low, T const & high, Compare greater)
{ /* your code here */ }
```

In `template` as used above, the words `typename` and `class` are synonyms. But *only* as used above - that's not always the case.